# Can Stripe be used to deposit money into a User Stripe account?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

How can I transfer from my Stripe account to users stripe account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is generally not supported, its considered a ["special-case" transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers).

In general, when you create a charge, you need to specify the Stripe account that should be receiving the charge. The methods for doing this are documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees).